# python uploading an image to a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-upload, directory

I use this code to upload an image to a directory:

```
import urllib.request
URL = ...
FILENAME = r'c:\networks\work\image1.jpg'
with urllib.request.urlopen(URL) as response:
  image = response.read()
  with open(FILENAME, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(image)
```

and it works for every image, but when I try to upload this type of URL:

```
https://data.cyber.org.il/python/logpuzzle/p-bbjb-bbia.jpg
```

the uploading takes something like 3 minutes which is very slow, why does it happen?

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Maybe you have a bad connection to this server or the website was temporarily overloaded?

Comment: do you have to same problem when you run url in browser? OR maybe server checn some other elements (headers, cookies) to block bots/spamers/hackers. Maybe check what you get in `image`. Maybe you get text with warning for bots or Captcha.

Comment: what's the size of the file?

Comment: I also can't confirm problem. I can download it in few milliseconds. BTW: shorter `urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, FILENAME)`